# Not connect gmail with python. Error is b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I want to check gmail's mail.

I wrote this code with python.

```
import imaplib
import email

UserName = "my_gmail"
PassName = "my_gmail_password"

gmail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", '993')
gmail.login(UserName, PassName)
gmail.select("")

head, data = gmail.search(None, 'ALL')
```

but occured this error.

> error                                     Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         8 
>         9 gmail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", '993')
>   ---> 10 gmail.login(UserName, PassName)
>        11 gmail.select("")
>        12
>
> ~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/imaplib.py in login(self, user,
>   password)
>       596         typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGIN', user, self._quote(password))
>       597         if typ != 'OK':
>   --> 598             raise self.error(dat[-1])
>       599         self.state = 'AUTH'
>       600         return typ, dat
>
> error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'

Why this error occure?
And how do I slove this error?
Please tell me.

Comment: Have you generated an App Specific Password or enabled "Less Secure Apps"?  Google filters out plain logins by default.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 2-FA? if so, you have to set an application-specific password via gmail, and send that password instead of your regular password.
Otherwise, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258509/how-to-use-google-application-specific-password-in-script) post might help.

It might cause a security hazard - but at least for the development stage you can go to your google account security settings and allow less secure apps (blocked by default).

Comment: As of May 30 2022, you cannot allow less secure apps
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en