# Connection refused when attempting to get access to gmail through jupyter lab inside a docker container

Tags: docker, gmail, jupyter-lab

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855227/google-authorization-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-with-jupyter-lab) sums up the majority of my question.

However, I am running my notebook inside a docker container. I also get a different error message. [Connection Refused Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDIIg.png)

The port I am using is localhost:9270.

How can I get the authorization to redirect back to my container and notebook?

I have tried using the above [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855227/google-authorization-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-with-jupyter-lab) and I was expecting the redirect to return me to my jupyter notebook. The redirect always changes the port number though.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to authenticate your application at google using user credentials. Have you tried application password at google? It seems to me they have easier way of authentication for apps.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. I have a jupyterlab server in a docker container and I'm trying to use OAuth to access my gmail account from a notebook on that lab server.

Comment: Will [this](https://blog.rebex.net/gmail-using-app-passwords) help?

Comment: I'd like to try it but is there a version for Python? I'm running Python in my jupyter notebook

Comment: It may differ depending which library you use. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10258509/21363224), it may help you understand how app password work. But basically  you ignore 2-step auth, and pass credentials programmatically.  As I said before how it is done really depends on library, so you should reference documtation of your, to find exact steps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to give it a shot and get back to you

Comment: @markalex, with the help of your suggestion and some further reading, I was able to generate a better search phrase and found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635990/reading-gmail-email-in-python that answer what I needed.